# Setting ruby hash .default to a list

Tags: ruby, hashmap

I thought I understood what the default method does to a hash...

Give a default value for a key if it doesn't exist:

```
irb(main):001:0> a = {}
=> {}
irb(main):002:0> a.default = 4
=> 4
irb(main):003:0> a[8]
=> 4
irb(main):004:0> a[9] += 1
=> 5
irb(main):005:0> a
=> {9=>5}
```

All good.

But if I set the default to be a empty list, or empty hash, I don't understand it's behaviour at **all**....

```
irb(main):001:0> a = {}
=> {}
irb(main):002:0> a.default = []
=> []
irb(main):003:0> a[8] << 9
=> [9]                          # great!
irb(main):004:0> a
=> {}                           # ?! would have expected {8=>[9]}
irb(main):005:0> a[8]
=> [9]                          # awesome!
irb(main):006:0> a[9]
=> [9]                          # unawesome! shouldn't this be [] ??
```

I was hoping/expecting the same behaviour as if I had used the ||= operator...

```
irb(main):001:0> a = {}
=> {}
irb(main):002:0> a[8] ||= []
=> []
irb(main):003:0> a[8] << 9
=> [9]
irb(main):004:0> a
=> {8=>[9]}
irb(main):005:0> a[9]
=> nil
```

Can anyone explain what is going on?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`Hash.default` is used to set the default value **returned** when you query a key that doesn't exist.  An entry in the collection is not created for you, just because queried it.

Also, the value you set `default` to is an instance of an object (an Array in your case), so when this is returned, it can be manipulated.

```
a = {}
a.default = []     # set default to a new empty Array
a[8] << 9          # a[8] doesn't exist, so the Array instance is returned, and 9 appended to it
a.default          # => [9]
a[9]               # a[9] doesn't exist, so default is returned
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that this behavior is different from python's defaultdict, where the analogous code works just fine.

Comment: Wow, this is horrible, and terribly prone to bugs by dynamically changing this default value.  I just spent 3 hours trying to figure out wtf was going on when attempting to set default to [].  IMNSHO, default should not be exposed like this.  The alternative (h=Hash.new{|h,k| h[k]=[]}) doesn't really do what I want either because that always creates a new array by just referencing the hash key.  Now I'm back to doing what I was trying to avoid in the first place: h[k]=[] unless h.has_key?(k)  :)

Comment: I hope you guys didn't down-vote this answer just for that peculiarity of Ruby itself :) What's wrong with this excellently explanatory answer? I myself hadn't completely gotten my head around the concept until I saw the emphasis on "returned" and the explanation on the importance of the value of `default` being an object (so that it's kept around in subsequent non-existent key calls).

Answer (score 56):

This is a very useful idiom:

```
(myhash[key] ||= []) << value
```

It can even be nested:

```
((myhash[key1] ||= {})[key2] ||= []) << value
```

The other way is to do:

```
myhash = Hash.new {|hash,key| hash[key] = []}
```

But this has the significant side-effect that **asking** about a key will create it, which renders has_key? fairly useless, so I avoid this method.

Comment: I don't think sure the side-effect of the last technique is present in ruby 1.9.2. myhash = Hash.new {|hash,key| hash[key] = []}; myhash.has_key?(:test) #=> false

Comment: Oh, no, I meant that `puts myhash[:test]` or the like, which seems like it should be harmless, will now result in `myhash.has_key?(:test)` being true afterwards.

Answer (score 34):

I think this is the behavior you are looking for. This will automatically initialize any new keys in the Hash to an array:

```
irb(main):001:0> h = Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = []}
=> {}
irb(main):002:0> h[1] << "ABC"
=> ["ABC"]
irb(main):003:0> h[3]
=> []
irb(main):004:0> h
=> {1=>["ABC"], 3=>[]}
```

Answer (score 9):

glenn mcdonald says:

"The other way is to do:

myhash = Hash.new {|hash,key| hash[key] = []}

But this has the significant side-effect that asking about a key will create it, which renders has_key? fairly useless, so I avoid this method."

that does not in fact seem to be true.

```
irb(main):004:0> a = Hash.new {|hash,key| hash[key] = []}
=> {}
irb(main):005:0> a.has_key?(:key)
=> false
irb(main):006:0> a[:key]
=> []
irb(main):007:0> a.has_key?(:key)
=> true
```

*Accessing* the key will create it, as I would expect. Merely asking has_key? does not.

Answer (score 9):

If you really wanna have an endlessly deep hash:

```
endless = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }
endless["deep"]["in"]["here"] = "hello"
```

Of course, as Glenn points out above, if you do this, the has_key? looses its meaning as it will always return true. Thx to jbarnette for this one.

Answer (score 6):

```
irb(main):002:0> a.default = []
=> []
irb(main):003:0> a[8] << 9
=> [9]                          # great!
```

With this statement, you have modified the default; you have not created a new array and added "9".  At this point, it's identical to if you had done this instead:

```
irb(main):002:0> a.default = [9]
=> [9]
```

Hence it's no surprise that you now get this:

```
irb(main):006:0> a[9]
=> [9]                          # unawesome! shouldn't this be [] ??
```

Furthermore, the '<<' added the '9' to the array; it did not add it to the hash, which explains this:

```
irb(main):004:0> a
=> {}                           # ?! would have expected {8=>[9]}
```

Instead of using .default, what you probably want to do in your program is something like this:

```
# Time to add a new entry to the hash table; this might be 
# the first entry for this key..
myhash[key] ||= []
myhash[key] << value
```

Answer (score -4):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you can do this to always return an empty array when a missing hash key is queried.

```
h = Hash.new { [] }
h[:missing]
   => []

#But, you should never modify the empty array because it isn't stored anywhere
#A new, empty array is returned every time
h[:missing] << 'entry'
h[:missing]
   => []
```