# How can I initialize an Array inside a Hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I am trying to initialize a Hash of Arrays such as

```
@my_hash = Hash.new(Array.new)
```

so that I can:

```
@my_hash["hello"].push("in the street")
=> ["in the street"]
@my_hash["hello"].push("at home")
=> ["in the street", "at home"]
@my_hash["hello"]
=>["in the street", "at home"]
```

The problem is that any new hash key also return `["in the street", "at home"]`

```
@my_hash["bye"]
=> ["in the street", "at home"]
@my_hash["xxx"]
=> ["in the street", "at home"]
```

!!!???

What am I doing wrong what would be the correct way to initialize a Hash of Arrays?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190740/setting-ruby-hash-default-to-a-list

Answer (score 100, accepted):

```
@my_hash = Hash.new(Array.new)
```

This creates exactly one array object, which is returned every time a key is not found. Since you only ever mutate that array and never create a new one, all your keys map to the same array.

What you want to do is:

```
@my_hash = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = Array.new }
```

or simply

```
@my_hash = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = [] }
```

Passing a block to `Hash.new` differs from simply passing an argument in 2 ways:

1. The block is executed every time a key is not found. Thus you'll get a new array each time. In the version with an argument, that argument is evaluated once (before `new` is called) and the result of that is returned every time.
2. By doing `h[k] =` you actually insert the key into the hash. If you don't do this just accessing `@my_hash[some_key]` won't actually cause `some_key` to be inserted in the hash.

Comment: The one gotcha to be aware of here is that now even *checking* a key will create it, which may not be what you want. For this reason I sometimes create the Hash normally (with just {}), and then do the array-creation in the call, like `(@myhash["hello"] ||= []).push("in the street")`.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
@my_hash = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Array.new }
```

Answer (score 2):

The argument for Hash.new is for the default value for new hash keys, so when you pass it a reference that reference will be used for new hash keys. You're updating that reference when you call...

```
hash["key"].push "value"
```

You need to pass a new reference into the hash key before pushing values to it...

```
hash["key1"] = Array.new
hash["key1"].push "value1"
hash["key2"] = Array.new
hash["key2"].push "value2
```

You could try encapsulating this into a helper method as well.